# How to load two checkpoints in init_fn in slim.learning.train

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I want to load two checkpoints while using `slim.learning.train`. For example,

```
init_fn = assign_from_checkpoint_fn(model_path, variables_to_restore)
slim.learning.train(train_op, log_dir, init_fn=init_fn)
```

The problem is that I can input only one checkpoint file in model_path. I want to put two checkpoints. I think there can be two possible solutions:

- Modify the following [assign_from_checkpoint_fn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py) function in `tf.contrib.framework.assign_from_checkpoint_fn` so that model_path can be a list of checkpoint files
- Merge two checkpoints before. (I didn't find any tool for this)

Is there anyone who help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: we can define our init function using session like this:

```
flow_init_assign_op, flow_init_feed_dict = slim.assign_from_checkpoint(
            flow_ckpt, flow_var_to_restore)

resnet_init_assign_op, resnet_init_feed_dict = 
slim.assign_from_checkpoint(
            resnet_ckpt, resnet_var_to_restore, ignore_missing_vars=True)

def init_fn(sess):
    sess.run(flow_init_assign_op, flow_init_feed_dict)
    sess.run(resnet_init_assign_op, resnet_init_feed_dict)
```